# Convert image to grayscale and reduce its resolution with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, jpeg

I have the following code that allows the user to **take a photo and then upload it to server** (that will eventually do further image processing).

```html
<form action="/submitphoto" method="post">
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="photo" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
</form>
```

It works. But very often (especially nowadays with high-megapixels phone cameras) :

- the image file will be very big (thus a long uploading time!), and too high unnecessary resolution for my application, e.g. 4000x6000 pixels
- the image will be color, whereas I only need grayscale

Of course I could do the JPG size reduction (e.g. 4000x6000 pixels to 800x1200 pixels) + color=>grayscale processing on server, but then *too-high uploading time / server processing time / bandwidth will be wasted*.

**Question: how to reduce the resolution of a JPG image taken with an `<input type="file" capture="camera" ...>` and transform it to grayscale prior to submitting the `form`, in Javascript?**

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I use [MarvinJ](https://www.marvinj.org) to resize and convert the image to gray scale before uploading to a server. These two operations are performed in javascript in the client-side as follows:

```
 Marvin.scale(image.clone(), image, 200);
 Marvin.grayScale(image.clone(), image);
```

I also included an implementation of an upload button and a method to POST the image to the server.

You can try the snippet. I hope it helps you.

```js
/***********************************************
 * GLOBAL VARS
 **********************************************/
var image = new MarvinImage();

/***********************************************
 * FILE CHOOSER AND UPLOAD
 **********************************************/
 $('#fileUpload').change(function (event) {
 form = new FormData();
 form.append('name', event.target.files[0].name);
 
 reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
 
 reader.onload = function(){
  image.load(reader.result, imageLoaded);
 };
});

function resizeAndSendToServer(){
  $("#divServerResponse").html("uploading...");
 $.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.marvinj.org/backoffice/imageUpload.php',
  data: form,
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,

  success: function (resp) {
       $("#divServerResponse").html("SERVER RESPONSE (NEW IMAGE):<br/><img src='"+resp+"' style='max-width:400px'></img>");
  },
  error: function (data) {
   console.log("error:"+error);
   console.log(data);
  },
  
 });
};
/***********************************************
 * IMAGE MANIPULATION
 **********************************************/
function imageLoaded(){
  Marvin.scale(image.clone(), image, 200);
  Marvin.grayScale(image.clone(), image);
  form.append("blob", image.toBlob());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.8.js"></script>
<form id="form" action='/backoffice/imageUpload.php' style='margin:auto;' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' id='fileUpload' class='upload' name='userfile'/>
</form><br/>
<button type="button" onclick="resizeAndSendToServer()">Resize and Send to Server</button><br/><br/>
<div id="divServerResponse">
</div>
```